# filebeat index creation seems not working in elasticsearch

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

According to this

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

we could create index like that

```css
curl -XPUT 'http://@IPELK:9200/_template/filebeat?pretty' -d@/PATH2/filebeat.template.json
```

When i launch that commande I receive as output :
{
  "acknowledged" : true
}

But still no having index created in Elastic search as we can see :

```css
[root] curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
health status index               pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   .kibana               1   1          3            1     15.1kb         15.1kb
yellow open   logstash-2016.01.12   5   1        115            0    142.4kb        142.4kb
[root]#
```

So, actually i have no communication between filebeat and my logstash :(
Any idea ?
Thx.

Comment: Can you show the content of `filebeat.template.json` and your logstash configuration?

Answer (score 1):

By removing _template like this

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/filebeat?pretty' -d@/path_2/filebeat.template.json

Comment: With that command you're creating an index, not a template. The goal of the template is for an index to be automatically created by ES as needed. When you create a template through `/_template`, you don't see any index yet, it's only after logstash sends its first document, that you're going to see the index. That's the whole point of an index template.